# Push notifications on distribution

Tags: php, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I create all certificates to develope push notify for my app iPhone. 
If I test it with file .pem created by developer certificates it work, but if I use file .pem created by production certificates it not work.

This is my code:

```
public function push($deviceToken,$badge,$message,$deviceType) {

              $sound = "default";

              // Construct the notification payload
              $body = array();
              $body['aps'] = array("alert" => $message);

              if ($badge)
                    $body['aps']['badge'] = $badge;
              if ($sound)
                    $body['aps']['sound'] = $sound;

              $ctx = stream_context_create();
              stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'apns-prod.pem');
              $fp = stream_socket_client("ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195", $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);

              if (!$fp) {
                    print "Failed to connect $err $errstrn";
                    return;
              } else {
                    print "Connection OK\n";
              }

              $payload = json_encode($body);
              $msg = chr(0) . pack('n',32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . pack('n',strlen($payload)) . $payload;
              fwrite($fp, $msg);
              fclose($fp);

    }
```

Any suggest?

Comment: HI Dany, Can you please update this, with solution worked for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Production push certificates will only work when you send notification to an app signed with an ad-hoc distribution certificate (or final release). Developer push certificates will only work with apps signed with a developer distribution certificate (ie installed to the device from XCode).

Comment: My app is on the apple-store with distribution certificates. Now I need send an update for my app adding push notification. Any suggest?

Comment: If you are testing using the production certificates, you will only see the notification come through if you have released the app through the AppStore OR if you install the app via ad-hoc distribution.

Comment: And how can I be sure it works without having to wait Apple's approval?

Comment: By using the ad-hoc distribution method rather than the developer distribution

Comment: I have created an ad-hoc distribution and but if I run the app it return an error: failed to send the qLaunchSuccess packet

Answer (score 0):

You can try your production certificate by changing you scheme properties:

- Click on your target scheme, on top left of Xcode window, then Edit Scheme.
- In the "Run yourTarget" tab, set `Release` as build configuration and "None" as debugger.
- Of course, your target must have an ad-hoc provisionning profile configured.
- Plug your iPhone and Run with iOSDevice configuration.

Does it work ?

**EDIT :** my appologizes, I would say `Release` instead of `Ad-hoc` (i corrected it)

Comment: but my app is public on apple store not ad-hoc

Comment: I would say `Release`. The Production Push Certificate is the same for `Release`and `App store` builds. If it works on `Release`, it will work on `App store`

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to create a NEW adhoc and or appstore distribution certificate AFTER creating the certificates for the push process. The adhoc and appstore certificates change for push-enables apps.